# Direct object and indirect object in the sentence "Bill promised Mary to fix her car."

Tags: objects, direct-objects, indirect-objects

In the following sentence

> Bill promised Mary to fix her car.

Maybe I can write this sentence like this:

> Bill promised Mary **(for Bill) to fix her car**.

Bill is the subject of the verb `fix`, and also the verb `promised`. So, `promised` will have two objects: *`Mary`* and the clause *`(for Bill) to fix her car`*, one is the direct object and the other is the indirect object.

Which is the direct object and Which is the indirect object? Why? (By the way, I don't know if it is right to analyse this sentence in this way.)

Comment: Incidentally, I probably wouldn't word this sentence with the preposition _to_. I'd say (or write): _Bill promised Mary he would fix her car,_ or, _Bill promised to fix Mary's car._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Promise*** is a very troublesome verb, syntactically speaking.

Most bitransitive communicational verbs, like *tell*, *order*, or *ask*, take infinitive complements with B-Equi from the Indirect Object, thus:

- `Su` *told/ordered/asked* `IO` [(*for* `IO`) *to* `VP`], as in
  *They told him to prune the peaches.

  She ordered him to leave immediately.

  I asked her to stop by after church.*

These cases are prototype examples of [B-Equi](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf), which means that the **Indirect Object** of the main clause is also understood to be the Subject of the infinitive clause.
*They* did the *telling* to *him*, while *he* did the *pruning*. Etc.

With *promise*, however, the pattern breaks:

- `Su` *promised* `IO` [(*for* `Su`) *to* `VP`], as in
  *She promised me to leave right after she talked to Bill.

  I promised her to take out the garbage.*

Here, *She* did the *promising*, **and** *she* was to do the *leaving*. In other words, it's the **Subject** of *promise* that is understood to be the subject of its infinitive, and **not** its Indirect Object, as in the prototype cases.  This is the pattern for A-Equi, where there is no Indirect Object, as in

- *She promised to be home before 11.*
- *She wanted to be home before 11.*
- *She tried to be home before 11.*
- *She managed to be home before 11.*

In these A-Equi cases, *She* is the subject of both the main clause and the infinitive.

It feels like *promise* is less bitransitive than [performative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Performative_verb). Performative verbs require an audience, and *promise*, in particular, requires someone (even if only oneself) to attend to the promise. But that's taken for granted, just like the audiences for *say*, or *swear*, or *claim*, or any other performative verb. The identity of the audience of performative verbs normally need not be expressed in the sentence; this allows *promise* to be more comfortable with A-Equi and without an indirect object.

*Promise* also feels more comfortable with a *that*-complement, when an indirect object is present:

- *I promised her that I would trim the magnolias after school tomorrow.*
- *I promised her to trim the magnolias after school tomorrow.*

In a tensed clause, of course, subjects are required and aren't deleted, so no reference problem arises.

Answer (score 2):

A dictionary actually helps here. This is part of the OED's definition for *promise*:

> **1.** *trans.* To make a promise of (something), to give verbal assurance of; to undertake or commit oneself to do or refrain from (a specified thing or act) or to give or bestow (a specified thing). Freq. with indirect object or with to and a noun phrase, indicating the person to whom the promise is made.
>
> **a.** With infinitive, expressing the act promised.
>
> > 1997   J. Hawes *Rancid Aluminium* (1998) xx. 242,   I had promised Sarah to take 1000mg of VitC+Zinc every night if I went drinking.
>
> **b.** With simple direct object, expressing the thing or act promised.
>
> > 2001   *Time* 30 Oct. 59/1   A cruel blow to parents who had promised Junior one of the first units.

Thus the indirect object is the person to whom the promise is made [Mary], and the direct object is what is actually promised [fixing her car].

In that respect, it's very similar to a simple verb like *give*. The direct object is **what** is given; the indirect object is **to whom** it is given.